# Why was my comment deleted, for this question about "where does the Value of Money go"?

Tags: support, comments

Specifically, this question on [Value of Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153107/where-does-the-value-of-money-go-during-inflation). I put a comment on the Question itself (two, actually, one in response to another person). All three comments are gone - any reason why? Alternately, is there any way to find out, other than posting here?

Answer (score 2):

I deleted it and the followups as it was an answer as a comment: [Should answers be left in the comments?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/should-answers-be-left-in-the-comments)

In general comments should be seen as temporary notes on questions only, not anything that can be expected to last long term.

Sometimes if a question isn't already answered well, I would leave a partial answer in a comment alone to see if it helped produce good answers, but this question already had several answers

In this case I acted in response to a flag from a user, but I'd probably have done so anyway if I'd come across it directly.

Comment: Kewl, tnx, I just wanted to know. When questions are deleted, you know why (duplicated, etc), and I could see no information on it.